# How do you use Google tasks API from an Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-tasks

I'd like to be able to create a custom app that uses Google tasks. How would I go about using Google tasks API from an Android app?

In other words, how do I make an API call and use the response?

I found a tutorial located [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/android) that was helpful.

Comment: Please post more details, Do you mean how to call the API and use the response?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Use any rest client, I recommend [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library

Comment: For Google task API read this doc https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/get_started and for API Request and Respose use Retrofit or Volley library.

Answer (score 0):

Register at [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com), enable the [Tasks API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/tasks.googleapis.com), and [create android authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred)

Add to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="25"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

Add to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev58-1.25.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.28.0'
```

Use [`AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%2520java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520boolean,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520android.os.Bundle)) to get an account, then:

```
String token = AccountManager.get(context)
    .getAuthToken(<android.accounts.Account>, "oauth2:" + TasksScopes.TASKS, new Bundle(), activity, null, null)
    .getResult()
    .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
Tasks service = new Tasks.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("app name")
    .build();
```

Now you can use the Tasks API, e.g. `service.tasklists().list().execute()`